How prevalent were pets among serfs and peasants in the middle ages?
I searched articles about this but most of them talked about the pets of the high society. Hunting dogs, cats eating mice in church, and so on. The wealthier classes are excluded from the scope of this question.
I will also consider as "pets" non-livestock animals of medium and small size. Those kept but not for the purpose of producing commodities. Also no horses. But the peasants didn't own horses, the vast majority.
But what about the relationship between pets and the lower classes, serfs and peasants? Did they keep pets? What tasks the pets executed? Did they have dogs or cats or birds or whatever? Did the sheep dog belong to the shepherd or to the herd owner? I think feeding a carnivore was hard since they didn't even get enough meat for themselves [1].

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b78z2jfglk  -> he is in the same page as you. But work animals (dogs for hunting, cat for mouse control, etc.) are not really pets by your own criteria, they are needed to produce commodities. He also cites lower class persons who  would care for their boss' pets.

I suspect this is an issue of definition. I suspect that the equivalent of "barn cats" were ubiquitous in the pre-modern world.  Animals that existed in  a sort of symbiotic relationship with human society. Both the human and the animals recognized mutual benefit.  We don't take barn cats to the vet, but we're happy to leave out scraps and water, and make sure they have a sheltered place, with perhaps some rags for a bed.  I cannot imagine that was not true throughout history.

I'm also not sure what kind of records/artifacts might exist? Perhaps accounts by monks of feeding birds/critters?

Friends who did 4H generally considered the (farm) animals they raised to be pets, even knowing they would be sold. Given all the cats, rabbits, squirrels, and dogs around farmyards I have no doubt that many adults and children had ones they considered pets as well. Just to powerful of a human urge.

Not my area of expertise, but a widely cited reference appears to be: Kathleen Walker-Meikle, Medieval Pets. Boydell Press 2012, 200 pp. Whether this specifically addresses the question of pets owned by serfs and peasants I do not know.

@MCW One could search literary sources such as Boccaccio, Chaucer, or Marco Polo, although I don't recall any mention of pets in Decameron, Canterbury Tales, and Travels. Archaeological excavations have yielded the bones of cats and dogs and these have been examined for indications of the animals' diet or butchering for meat / pelts. However, I am not aware of any such research in the specific context of medieval peasantry.

Anecdotally, drawing on conversations with early 20th Century east European peasants, such animals were not kept as pets as is currently practiced in most urbanized societies. Peasants didn't have the money to feed "empty mouths". All animals had to serve a useful function. Despite allowing cats to spend time inside a dwelling, particularly in cold winter nights, they were kept to control vermin. Similarly, dogs were kept as guard animals, alerting people to the presence of a potential danger or unusual situation. Also, some dogs could control larger vermin.

@MCW Cats in medieval manuscripts  (also by Kathleen Walker-Meikle) collects hints from one type of source, also this article (Bangor University) has some hints (e.g. search "Bromyard")

The question is impossibly broad and might warrant a book-length answer, but I'll mention that Hanawalt's book on peasant families in medieval England has a few passing references to dogs and cats. They "wandered in and out at will" from  villagers homes (p. 147). There is scant evidence of modern sentimentality about dogs and cats as family members, and each creature clearly had a primary function as described in the question (hunting for dogs, pest control for cats). However the fact that "[r]ules for polite society included not petting dogs and cats at the table" (p. 60) implies that at least some people were inclined to do so.
A book chapter by Emily Cockayne documents the major nuisances posed by street dogs in late medieval England. For a much broader perspective, you might track down another book chapter, "Animals in Medieval Perceptions: The image of the Ubiquitous Other" by Esther Cohen.
